# Copy One Files from one directory to another using Java & Ubuntu Docker

Tags: java, docker, file, ubuntu, processbuilder

I am trying to copy files from one directory to another. Say I have a directory named `Tony` and wish to copy the files from `Tony` to `Stark`, I use the below code:

```
String command = "cp -r Tony/ Stark/";
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = run.exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

Running the above code on Mac OS - Copies just the files from `Tony` to `Stark` while in Ubuntu based Docker, it copies the directory `Tony` into `Stark`. How do I handle this case? I tried to use `Tony/*` but strangely that runs in Terminal but does not work in Java.

Comment: Did you try with a . ? cp -r Tony/. Stark/ Why dont you use java FIles.copy( src, dst)

Comment: Files.copy gives a error - Stark/ already exists as the folder is already there. I wish to copy files into it. The last option would obviously be to run a loop and copy each file one after the other - However, I am looking to do it in a simpler way

Comment: @isma3l - The "." worked :)